# ReSharper Daemon Cannot be Enabled

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I was having a problem with ReSharper with one project, and I found in the internet that the daemon can be disabled using `Shift + Ctrl + Alt + 8`. This shortcut is also supposed to re-enable the daemon, but the daemon cannot be enabled anymore (pressing the shortcut doesn't do anything).

Does anybody have a solution to this problem? Is there any other way to enable the daemon?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For anyone experiencing the same problem, it appears to be a problem with Visual Studio. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything, but it didn't work.

To resolve the issue, I had to delete the `VisualStudio` directory inside `%APPDATA%\Microsoft` directory, and restart Visual Studio.

Of course it would help if you have a backup of your settings, so that you can restore your settings after you delete the directory.